# COM Object behaving differently in ASP Classic and VBscript

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, exchange-server, com+

----- this issue was solved, doesn't relate to subject see explanation at bottom -----

I've put together a C# dll that I'm running as a COM object to handle Exchange Server processing.  One of functions it performs creates a users mailbox.  I've set up a COM+ application so it's running as an Exchange Administrator.

When CreateObject in VBScript and call the function, it works.  When I do the same thing in an ASP page (using Server.CreateObject) it does nothing.

Any ideas as to what different behaviors I should be looking for between VBscript and ASP Classic in this case?

The DLL code being executed:

```
public void CreateMailbox(String database, String dc, String upn)
{
    String retval = String.Empty;
    Dictionary<String, object> args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    args.Add("Identity", upn);
    args.Add("Database", database);
    args.Add("DomainController", dc);            
    Collection<PSObject> result = ExecuteCmdlet("Enable-Mailbox", args);
    return;
}
```

And ExecuteCmdlet

```
private Collection<PSObject> ExecuteCmdlet(String cmdlet, Dictionary<String,object> arguments)
{
    RunspaceConfiguration rsConf = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
    PSSnapInException psException = null;
    PSSnapInInfo psInfo = rsConf.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin", out psException);
    Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConf);
    rs.Open();
    Pipeline pipe = rs.CreatePipeline();
    Command psCmd = new Command(cmdlet);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<String,object> arg in arguments)
    {
        psCmd.Parameters.Add(arg.Key, arg.Value);
    }
    pipe.Commands.Add(psCmd);
    Collection<PSObject> retVal = pipe.Invoke();
    rs.Close();
    return retVal;
}
```

EDIT: This seems to be an issue with my ASP implementation, which involves me trying to tie it into a 3rd party AD management tool.  When I use the code in a stand alone ASP page, it works.  Seems like this requires some more research on my part.

EDIT2: A couple hours of research hasn't yielded anything on the way IIS handles COM+ objects that have a bound identity in any way indicating the problem.  The VBS requested is below.  This works.  This exact same code works in an ASP Classic web page.  When I run this exact same code in a different web app in the same vdir, it fails to create the mailbox.  The app in question is a MVC front end to Active Directory written in ASP Classic.

```
Dim exch
Set exch = CreateObject("ExchangeMailboxCreator.ExchangeMailboxBuilder")
exch.CreateMailbox("Mailbox\SG\DB", "domaincontroller.domain.com", "TestUserAccount")
```

FINAL EDIT: Unsurprisingly, this was an issue not with the above code, but with the code around it.  The application I was integrating with was using AD LDS as a staging directory before periodically writing back to AD.  This meant my attempts to directly touch Exchange were failing because the AD account didn't exist.  I hacked my way around it by adding a loop to sleep until the Exchange environment recognized the user existed.  Not... my favorite solution ever, but I'll take it.  Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: You've left out the important bit, your actual VBScript code.

Answer (score 1):

On the "Security" tab in Component Services you need to uncheck "Enforce access checks for this application".

Comment: Actually I don't think that is good advice considering what this component is doing.  It grants any process running under even a highly restricted security token to do things with an exchange server.

Comment: This is the solution to the problem. I believe the point of the app he's writing is to allow anyone to do things with the Exchange server.

Comment: Its _a_ solution but a dangerous one. There are others that allow the ASP code to run under an account that has the required access in first place.  This would restrict the exposure only the specific task that the ASP code is doing.

Comment: I actually already had that field unchecked on this COM application.  This seems to be an issue with my ASP implementation, which involves me trying to tie it into a 3rd party AD management tool.  When I use the code in a stand alone ASP page, it works.  Seems like this requires some more research on my part.  Thanks for the help